# How to remove button from form element? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have this html

```
<form id="form">

<input id="deleteNumber" name="del" type="hidden" />
<input id="addAddress" name="addAddress" type="hidden" />

...
...
...

<a href="javascript:deleteAddress();" class="deleteItem"/></a>
<a href="javascript:addNextAddress()">Add address </a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addNextAddress() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('form');
    var child = document.getElementById('form').del;
    perent.removeChild(child);
    document.getElementById('form').submit();   
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteAddress() {
    var r=confirm(text);
    if (r == true) {
        var parent = document.getElementById('form');
        var child = document.getElementById('form').addAddress;
        perent.removeChild(child);
        document.getElementById('form').submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

I get js error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: perent is not
>   defined

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try now

```
var parent = document.getElementById('form');
var child = document.getElementById('form').addAddress;
parent.removeChild(child);
document.getElementById('form').submit();
```

or change Parent to perent :)

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/187073) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 2):

its just a typo in this function:

```
function addNextAddress() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('form');
    var child = document.getElementById('form').del;
    perent.removeChild(child);//<-- change perent to parent
    document.getElementById('form').submit();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `perent.removeChild(child)` to `parent.removeChild(child)`.

You have a spelling mistake -- `perent` is not defined anywhere in your code, which is why you see "perent is not defined".